# Can multiple CNAMEs cause ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Unsuccessfully trying to set up a CloudFront distribution for a static AWS-bucket based website, which worked with http, but not https.  After adding certificate and configuring CloudFront, I am getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Can the problem be the multiple CNAMEs for mywebsite, configured in Route 53?
2 records are from certificate manager validation, not sure where the others came from.

Thank you!

```dns
mywebsite.com   A   Simple  -   
dwm6otdm3onq4.cloudfront.net.

mywebsite.com   MX  Simple  -   
10 inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

mywebsite.com   NS  Simple  -   
ns-480.awsdns-60.com.
ns-1803.awsdns-33.co.uk.
ns-622.awsdns-13.net.
ns-1286.awsdns-32.org.

mywebsite.com   SOA Simple  -   
ns-480.awsdns-60.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

_ab7fff75e12e479a02ad7b663442718d.mywebsite.com CNAME   Simple  -   
_ffb36079eac41a4ec0d793858a8756ae.cvfdyspdbk.acm-validations.aws.

_amazonses.mywebsite.com    TXT Simple  -   
"16fq2E3zX5omvpZj0u/Wjf3U3Qky9a5eI/G8FQdp2VA="

c43idfnpaak4u3nh3znyjcezzfgjbza7._domainkey.mywebsite.com   CNAME   Simple  -   
c43idfnpaak4u3nh3znyjcezzfgjbza7.dkim.amazonses.com

n3b4lhcvp63woqnod6tlgpovm5dcpqkz._domainkey.mywebsite.com   CNAME   Simple  -   
n3b4lhcvp63woqnod6tlgpovm5dcpqkz.dkim.amazonses.com.

tgfvwhfjzfmn4cfpalcjlxrb7vfutszu._domainkey.mywebsite.com   CNAME   Simple  -   
tgfvwhfjzfmn4cfpalcjlxrb7vfutszu.dkim.amazonses.com

autodiscover.mywebsite.com  CNAME   Simple  -   
autodiscover.mail.us-east-1.awsapps.com

www.mywebsite.com   A   Simple  -   
dwm6otdm3onq4.cloudfront.net.

_b6ae735a7252c03dbfbe162ec5be00cc.www.mywebsite.com CNAME   Simple  -   
_16d9e15225e215d9fd9e9876ce29c409.cvfdyspdbk.acm-validations.aws.
```

```json
{
    "ETag": "E2UARY2PF3JN6L",
    "Distribution": {
        "Id": "E2VAMJ3R5UEYSD",
        "ARN": "arn:aws:cloudfront::098706368979:distribution/E2VAMJ3R5UEYSD",
        "Status": "Deployed",
        "LastModifiedTime": "2021-08-18T19:41:28.165Z",
        "InProgressInvalidationBatches": 0,
        "DomainName": "dwm6otdm3onq4.cloudfront.net",
        "ActiveTrustedSigners": {
            "Enabled": false,
            "Quantity": 0
        },
        "DistributionConfig": {
            "CallerReference": "49a807de-37a4-4c9f-add6-739dcffd27cb",
            "Aliases": {
                "Quantity": 2,
                "Items": [
                    "www.mywebsite.com",
                    "mywebsite.com"
                ]
            },
            "DefaultRootObject": "index.html",
            "Origins": {
                "Quantity": 2,
                "Items": [
                    {
                        "Id": "www.mywebsite.com.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
                        "DomainName": "mywebsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
                        "OriginPath": "",
                        "CustomHeaders": {
                            "Quantity": 0
                        },
                        "CustomOriginConfig": {
                            "HTTPPort": 80,
                            "HTTPSPort": 443,
                            "OriginProtocolPolicy": "match-viewer",
                            "OriginSslProtocols": {
                                "Quantity": 3,
                                "Items": [
                                    "TLSv1",
                                    "TLSv1.1",
                                    "TLSv1.2"
                                ]
                            },
                            "OriginReadTimeout": 30,
                            "OriginKeepaliveTimeout": 5
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Id": "mywebsite.com.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
                        "DomainName": "mywebsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
                        "OriginPath": "",
                        "CustomHeaders": {
                            "Quantity": 0
                        },
                        "CustomOriginConfig": {
                            "HTTPPort": 80,
                            "HTTPSPort": 443,
                            "OriginProtocolPolicy": "http-only",
                            "OriginSslProtocols": {
                                "Quantity": 3,
                                "Items": [
                                    "TLSv1",
                                    "TLSv1.1",
                                    "TLSv1.2"
                                ]
                            },
                            "OriginReadTimeout": 30,
                            "OriginKeepaliveTimeout": 5
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "OriginGroups": {
                "Quantity": 0
            },
            "DefaultCacheBehavior": {
                "TargetOriginId": "www.mywebsite.com.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
                "ForwardedValues": {
                    "QueryString": false,
                    "Cookies": {
                        "Forward": "none"
                    },
                    "Headers": {
                        "Quantity": 0
                    },
                    "QueryStringCacheKeys": {
                        "Quantity": 0
                    }
                },
                "TrustedSigners": {
                    "Enabled": false,
                    "Quantity": 0
                },
                "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "redirect-to-https",
                "MinTTL": 0,
                "AllowedMethods": {
                    "Quantity": 2,
                    "Items": [
                        "HEAD",
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "CachedMethods": {
                        "Quantity": 2,
                        "Items": [
                            "HEAD",
                            "GET"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "SmoothStreaming": false,
                "DefaultTTL": 0,
                "MaxTTL": 0,
                "Compress": true,
                "LambdaFunctionAssociations": {
                    "Quantity": 0
                },
                "FieldLevelEncryptionId": ""
            },
            "CacheBehaviors": {
                "Quantity": 0
            },
            "CustomErrorResponses": {
                "Quantity": 0
            },
            "Comment": "",
            "Logging": {
                "Enabled": false,
                "IncludeCookies": false,
                "Bucket": "",
                "Prefix": ""
            },
            "PriceClass": "PriceClass_100",
            "Enabled": true,
            "ViewerCertificate": {
                "ACMCertificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:098706368979:certificate/8213cadd-5efd-44ad-b252-3d2cb7bed408",
                "SSLSupportMethod": "sni-only",
                "MinimumProtocolVersion": "TLSv1.2_2021",
                "Certificate": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:098706368979:certificate/8213cadd-5efd-44ad-b252-3d2cb7bed408",
                "CertificateSource": "acm"
            },
            "Restrictions": {
                "GeoRestriction": {
                    "RestrictionType": "none",
                    "Quantity": 0
                }
            },
            "WebACLId": "",
            "HttpVersion": "http2",
            "IsIPV6Enabled": true
        },
        "AliasICPRecordals": [
            {
                "CNAME": "www.mywebsite.com",
                "ICPRecordalStatus": "APPROVED"
            },
            {
                "CNAME": "mywebsite.com",
                "ICPRecordalStatus": "APPROVED"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

get-bucket-policy

```json
    {
        "Policy": "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"PublicReadGetObject\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"s3:GetObject\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:s3:::mywebsite.com/*\"},{\"Sid\":\"PublicReadGetObjectVersion\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"s3:GetObjectVersion\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:s3:::mywebsite.com/*\"},{\"Sid\":\"PublicListBucket\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"s3:ListBucket\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:s3:::mywebsite.com\"}]}"
    }
```

get-bucket-website:

```json
    { 
        "IndexDocument": {
            "Suffix": "index.html"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd guess it's a problem with your CloudFront configuration and not your route 53 configuration, since everything looks normal. Can you share your CloudFront configuration as well?

Comment: @stijndepestel, thank you, it certainly might be, even though I seemingly followed instructions.  I tried mywebsite.com.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com and mywebsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com as domain origin.  Behavior says redirect HTTP to HTTPS, not much was changed.  Is there a good way to get a compact report on the setting, since I have 2 www.mywebstie.com (which should be redirected to mywebsite.com) or anything specific I can look up?

Comment: do you have a cloudformation template for those by any chance? That would show the entire configuration in yaml, which would give a good overview.

Comment: @stijndepestel, I got the CLI get-distribution output, but it's too big to post as a comment.  Would it be possible for you to email me flareplf@yahoo.com, so I can reply with info?  Thank you!

Comment: Now getting 504s :(.

Comment: You can edit your original question to post your distribution output.

Comment: @stijndepestel, thank you for the suggestion, added some CLI output for CloudFront and the bucket

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see what is causing the redirects, but it is clear that your CloudFront configuration is not really ideal. You've got the same origin configured twice (while only using one) and they are configured to also use HTTPS to access S3, which is not supported. They are also configured using a custom HTTP origin, while it is a little more secure to use the S3 origin configuration with an [Origin Access Identity (OAI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html).

You can use [this blog](https://medium.com/@sameera.godakanda/using-cloudfront-to-allow-public-access-to-content-in-private-s3-bucket-2b01b041966e) as a base to set it up using an OAI. This will probably/hopefully also fix your redirection issues.

Comment: stijndepestel, thank you, I am getting 504s now (as I noted in the comment above) with no changes.  Thanks for the blog reference.  I am def. not a web guy, but I am puzzled why is it so difficult to configure a https access to a simple static website, residing in S3 bucket.  The website won't contain any restricted information, all public stuff, and it works statically if I just use the http and bucket website endpoint. Anyhow, thanks for your help.

Comment: I removed one of the origins after you comment, since I realized that both are resolved via Route 52 A record to the same CloudFront distribution, so I only need one (I was actually following a web article when I configured it).

Answer (score 0):

Adding an AAA record fixed the issue.